# Sybase IQ restrict IP

Tags: database, sybase, database-administration, sap-iq

I'm trying to restrict certain users by the IP or hostname in Sybase IQ 12.7.
I could only find how to do it in Sybase ASE. Can it be done in Sybase IQ 12.7? I could not find any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this before, and I've not used version 12 either, but have you looked at creating a login procedure?

The documentation here should explain how to do it.

http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1270/html/iqapg/X100726.htm

Within the procedure check the node address property from sp_iqconnection, which if the connection is remote will contain the ip address.

Good luck.

Derek.